# How to replace a fractional number by latex \frac globally

Tags: bash, vim, sh

I have a very large expression which contains many fractional numbers (a/b). I want to replace all fractional numbers by their latex form i.e. my output would be \frac{a}{b} globally. Here is a part of the input file:

```
      + 93
      - 220/3*zeta3
      + 536/9*zeta2
      - 4/5*zeta2^2
```

My output would be something like :

```
      + 93
      - \frac{220}{3}*zeta3
      + \frac{536}{9}*zeta2
      - \frac{4}{5}*zeta2^2
```

I can do it manually by vim editor (which is very time consuming). I was looking for a script which can do it globally for all such fractions. Is it possible to do in shell script?

Answer (score 3):

With GNU sed:

```
sed -E 's|([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)|\\frac{\1}{\2}|' file
```

Output:

```
      + 93
      - \frac{220}{3}*zeta3
      + \frac{536}{9}*zeta2
      - \frac{4}{5}*zeta2^2
```

Comment: With 'g' at the end if there is multiple fraction per line 's|...|...|g'

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your fractions consist only of numbers, and they don't span multiple lines:

```
:%s!\v(\d+)\s*/\s*(\d+)!\\frac{\1}{\2}!g
```

Comment: Or an `ex(1)` command, because of `:%s`.  But since common incarnations of `ex(1)` don't support `\v`, and since the question is tagged `vim`, it might be safer to go with Vim. ;)

Answer (score 0):

using regex :

```
match : ^(\s+(\+|\-)\s+)(\d+)\/(\d+)(\*.*)$
replace : \1\\frac{\3}{\4}\5
```

use tools such as `sed` to edit file.

see [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/sK2dX3/1)

Answer (score 0):

Usually, when you think:

> I can do it manually by vim editor (which is very time consuming).

You're doing something wrong, since nothing should take long in the vim editor, thus:

## Use a vim macro

First search for `/`:

```
<esc>/\/
```

Record the following macro:

```
nbifrac{<esc>nvc}{<esc>ea}<esc>
```

## Step by step

Start recording a macro in buffer `q`:

```
qq
```

Find next occurrence of `/`

```
n
```

Step in front of numerator and insert `frac{`:

```
bifrac{<esc>
```

Find the division sign, select it and change it to `}{`:

```
nvc}{<esc>
```

Step over denominator and append `}`:

```
ea}<esc>
```

Stop recording macro:

```
q
```

Play the macro 1000 times if you like:

```
1000@q
```